# Custom SQL Function For Generating Year Wise Client Code

Tags: c#, sql-server

**SQL Function For Generating Year Wise Client Code:** 
The following sql function will generate year wise client code based on server-date. such as for 2012 client the codes will be

`CL12-00001`, `CL12-00002`,....and for 2013 the codes will be

`CL13-00001`, `CL13-00002`,....etc.

(Here CL means client, 12 for year 2012, 13 for year 2013.)

```
CREATE function [dbo].[GenClientCode]() 
returns nvarchar(20) 
as 
begin 
Declare @Code nvarchar(20), @cyear nvarchar(2);
SET @cyear= ( SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(year, sysdatetime())),3,2));
SET  @Code= (Select MAX(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ClientCode,6, LEN(ClientCode))))+1 
             from tblClientInfo WHERE   SUBSTRING(ClientCode,3,2)=@cyear);
            --assume the code format is like CL12-00001, here 12 for year 2012

if (@Code is null or @Code='') 
set @Code='00001'
else if LEN(@Code)=1
set @Code='0000'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(1),@Code);
else if LEN(@Code)=2
set @Code='000'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(2),@Code);
else if LEN(@Code)=3
set @Code='00'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(3),@Code);
else if LEN(@Code)=4
set @Code='0'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(4),@Code);

set @Code='CL'+@cyear+'-'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@Code); 
return @Code;
end
```

*Is my function is optimum or not?*

Comment: What is "year wise client code"?

Comment: Maybe it's new entity type with so high importance to deserve new tag type... :)

Comment: No it's not optimum, never will be, intelligent numbers are dumb

Answer (score 0):

Getting `MAX+1` for the next record is not very accurate. Better solution would be to have an `auto incremented identity(1,1) column`, *say IdCol* and a `date column`, *say dateCol*. Then you can form your specific code on `SELECT` *as*;

```
SELECT 'CL' + RIGHT(DATEPART(yy,dateCol),2) + '-' + 
                RIGHT('00000' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),idCol),5) 
                --Note:Max clients 99999
```

*However, your function also can be optimised as;*

```
CREATE function [dbo].[GenClientCode]() 
returns varchar(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 

    Declare @code varchar(20), @cyear varchar(2);

    SELECT @cyear = RIGHT(DATEPART(yy,Getdate()),2);

    SELECT @code =  ISNULL( MAX(
                            SUBSTRING(ClientCode, CHARINDEX('-', ClientCode) + 1,
                            LEN(ClientCode))
                          ), 0)+1 
    FROM tblClientInfo 
    WHERE SUBSTRING(ClientCode,3,2) = @cyear

    RETURN 'CL' + @cyear + '-' + RIGHT('00000' + @code, 5)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea has several obvious problems such as "what happens in the year 2100?" and "what happens if there more than 99999 codes in a year?".  Also there are a few less obvious issues such as "what happens if two codes are requested at nearly the same time?" and the fact that you're doing a query off a substring which means that SQL Server can't use an index (meaning your performance may be bad).

"How do I get a 2-digit year?" and "how do I left-pad strings?" seems to have been answered by Kaf.

If you're on SQL Server 2012, I would suggest looking into sequences.  If you're on an earlier version, I would suggest putting a new table into your database with two integer fields representing the year and the next available number for that year and then changing your scalar function to a stored procedure that is able to query and update that table using an exclusive lock.  This would allow you to find the next number quickly using an indexed small table rather than doing a table scan over what I assume to be a large table.  Also this would help protect you from possible duplicates if your system is under pressure.